# How can I show recent blogbost from wp multisites on my mainpage

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm having some trouble with wordpress. I'm rather new to wordpress and are not that familiar with how everything works.
With that said, I'm working on a project in Wordpress that incluedes a main site and a couple of different sub sites. I'm using Wordpress multisites.

What I want to do is to show the latest blogpost from every sub site on my mainsite.

I know how to fix it with only one site:

```
<?php $the_query = new WP_query('posts_per_page=6'); ?>
  <?php while ($the_query -> have_posts()) : $the_query -> the_post(); ?>   
    <a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>"><div class="col-md-3 col-xs-12">

      <p><i class="fa fa-user"></i> <?php the_author(); ?>
      <i class="fa fa-clock-o"></i> <time><?php the_date(); ?></time></p>

      <?php $email = get_the_author_meta('', $author); ?>
      <?php $bild = get_avatar_url($email); ?>
      <img src="<?php echo $bild; ?>" id="avatarimg">

       <h3><?php the_title(); ?></h3>


    </div></a>
    <?php
        endwhile;
        wp_reset_postdata();

    ?>
```

The above codesnippet works with only a single wordpress site and it's excactly how I want it to works just for multiple sites.

What I have managed to do is actually to fetch the blogposts from the other sites using this code:

```
<?php
  $all_blog = get_sites();
  foreach ($all_blog as $key=>$current_blog) {
    // switch to each blog to get the posts
    switch_to_blog($current_blog->blog_id);
      // fetch all the posts
      $blog_posts = get_posts(array( 'posts_per_page' => 1));
      restore_current_blog();
        // display all posts
        echo $blog_posts[0]->post_content;
  }

?>
```

This code gives me all the content from the recent blog posts from all blogs. What I havn't figured out is how to display the data just like in the first codesnippet.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how to directly help you.

But perhaps if you take a look at WPMUDEV Autopost plugin code you might find the answer. I used it some time ago to do this very thing.

B.R.

Answer (score 0):

I came up with the answer that I was looking for. It was a rather simple solution but It took some time for me as a novice to figure it out.

I just had to write out the information I wanted in the foreach loop under the comment section //display al posts, so it looks like this:

```
<?php
$all_blog = get_sites();
foreach ($all_blog as $key=>$current_blog) {
 // switch to each blog to get the posts
 switch_to_blog($current_blog->blog_id);
 // fetch all the posts
  $blog_posts = get_posts(array( 'posts_per_page' => 1));
  restore_current_blog();
    // display all posts
    //echo $blog_posts[0]->post_content;
}

?>

<a href="<?php echo $blog_posts[0]->guid; ?>"><div class="col-xs-12 col-md-3">
<?php $author_name = the_author_meta('display_name', $blog_posts[0]->post_author); ?>
<p><i class="fa fa-user"></i> <?php echo $author_name; ?>
<i class="fa fa-clock-o"></i> <time><?php echo $blog_posts[0]->post_date_gmt; ?></time></p>

<?php $bild = get_avatar_url($blog_posts[0]->post_author); ?>
<img src="<?php echo $bild; ?>" id="avatarimg">

<h3><?php echo $blog_posts[0]->post_title; ?></h3>
</div></a>
```